# Renaming Github account name while already a team member

Tags: github

I have two accounts: account_1 and account_2 with two different e-mails, mail_1 and mail_2, respectively (both the accounts are backed-up, there is no concern of work loss).
I am a part of Team_X with account_1 and mail_1, but I am told to be a part of Team_X with account_2 & mail_2.

Does, renaming account_1 to account_old and renaming account_2 to account_1 suffice the requirement?
Or, do I have to additionally change my primary mail address from mail_1 to mail_2 too?

Or, are there any other steps that you can perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be ask the Team manager or concerned person to remove your old account from Team_X and add new new one. This will impact your work and commit history, You new user id will be shown for new commits.

another better way would be just remove your mail_1  from account_1 and mail_2 from account_2 and attach the mail_2 to account_1. Now you can change your username from account_1 to account_2.

There are repercussion of doing these things.

```
Like After changing your username, your old username becomes available
for anyone else to claim. If the new owner of your old username creates a repository 
with the same name as your repository, that will override the redirect
 entry and your redirect will stop working.
```

So deal it with precautions.

Comment: As the team is too big, I am asking for another work-around. I've tried the other way half-way right now. Also, I cannot upvote right now because I have less reputation.
Your answer helps!